# Forking once and then use the threads in a different procedure?

Tags: c++, fortran, openmp

If I fork inside my main program and then call a subroutine inside a single directive, what is the behavior if I enter an OMP parallel directive in this subroutine?

My guess/hope is that existing threads are used, as they all should have nothing to do at the moment.

Pseudo-Example:

```
double A[];

int main() {
   #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
   {
      #pragma omp single
      {
         for (int t=0; t<1000; t++) {
            evolve();
         }
      }
   }
}

 void evolve() {
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
       do_stuff(i);
    }
 }

 void do_stuff(int i) {
    // expensive calculation on array element A[i]
 }
```

As `evolve()` is called very often, forking here would cause way to much overhead, so I would like to do it only once, then call `evolve()` from a single thread and split the work of the calls to `do_stuff()` over the existing threads.

For Fortran this seems to work. I get a roughly 80-90% speed increase on a simple example using 2 threads. But for C++ I get a different behavior, only the thread which executes the single directive is used for the loop in `evolve()`

I fixed the problem using the task directive in the main program and passing the limits to `evolve()`, but this looks like a clumsy solution...

Why is the behavior in Fortran and C++ different and what would be the solution in C++?

Comment: While I do appreciate the edit, "behaviour" is the british english version. Not everyone speaks american english, you know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe *orphaned directives* are the cleanest solution in your case:

```
double A[];

int main() {
   #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
   {
     // Each thread calls evolve() a thousand times
     for (int t=0; t<1000; t++) {
        evolve();
     }
   }
}

 void evolve() {
    // The orphaned construct inside evolve()
    // will bind to the innermost parallel region
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
       do_stuff(i);
    } // Implicit thread synchronization
 }

 void do_stuff(int i) {
    // expensive calculation on array element A[i]
 }
```

This will work because (section 2.6.1 of the standard):

> A loop region binds to the innermost enclosing **parallel** region

That said, in your code you are using *nested parallel constructs*. To be sure to enable them you must set the environment variable `OMP_NESTED` to `true`, otherwise (quoting Appendix E of the latest standard):

> **OMP_NESTED environment variable**: if the value is neither **true** nor **false** the behavior is implementation defined

Comment: I did not know about orphaned directives. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your code will likely not work as expected in all cases.  If you have a code structure like this:

```
void foo() {
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single 
   bar();
}
void bar() {
#pragma omp parallel
   printf("...)";
}
```

OpenMP is requested to create a new team of threads when entering the parallel region in bar.  OpenMP calls that "nested parallelism".  However, what exactly happens depends on the your actual implementation of OpenMP used and the setting of OMP_NESTED.

OpenMP implementations are not required to support nested parallelism.  It would be perfectly legal, if an implementation ignored the parallel region in bar and just execute it with one thread.  OMP_NESTED can be used to turn on and off nesting, if the implementation supports it.

In your case, things by chance went well, since you sent all threads to sleep except one.  This thread then created a new team of threads of full size (potentially NEW threads, not reusing the old ones).  If you omitted the single construct, you would easily get thousands of threads.

Unfortunately, OpenMP does not support your pattern to create a parallel team, have one thread executing the call stacks, and then distribute work across the other team members through a worksharing construct like for.  If you need this code pattern, the only solution will be OpenMP tasks.

Cheers,
        -michael

Comment: -1 For the last paragraph which is not true: you may have _all_ threads executing the call stack and then sharing the work inside a function, even though the `parallel` region was not declared in the same scope

Comment: Maybe there's a small misunderstanding here: What is not supported is the pattern of having just ONE thread executing the call stack.  I did not mean to say that OpenMP does not support having a worksharing construct somewhere in down in the call stack.  But the requirement, as you say, is that ALL threads execute the call stack.

Comment: I had to fake edit the answer to remove the downvote (as the issue is now better clarified clarified in the comment)

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't actually call `fork()`, so I suspect you don't mean fork in the system-call sense (i.e. duplicating your process). However, if that really is what you meant, I suspect that most OpenMP implementations will not work correctly in a forked process. Typically, threads are not preserved across `fork()` calls. If the OpenMP implementation you use registers `pthread_atfork()` handlers, it may work correctly following a `fork()` call, but it will not use the same threads as the parent process.